# Scala: is there a way to create inline types?

Tags: scala, types, inline, type-systems, singleton-type

Basically, I'd like to be able to write something like this:

```
val x :('k1.type, Int) = 'k1 -> 1
val y :('k2.type, Int) = 'k2 -> 2
```

Where types of x and y are not compatible, but either share a super type or can be annotated with context bounds, allowing me to do something like this:

```
def mlt[T :MyLittleType](x :(T, Int)) = ???
mlt(x); mlt(y)
```

Keywords are used here only as an example, the goal is to be able to provide both literals and singleton types for some identifiers/keywords/strings. The types might as well get erased/unified in runtime, I am interested only in static type check.  I guess it should be possible to attain this using macros, but I would rather not.

Comment: I guess you want something like [literal-based singleton types](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/42.type.html).

Comment: Which are, IIRC, available in [Typelevel's fork](https://github.com/typelevel/scala) of the Scala compiler.

Comment: Alternately, are [shapeless records](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#extensible-records) what you want?

Comment: Yes, this SIP is exactly what I want. I hoped that since we have .type for identifiers, there could be some trick to use it for literals. I was aware of shapeless records, but the above is a simplified version of a problem I am trying to solve and shapeless records would be a bit too verbose for my needs. I would encounter objections for introducing it to the project anyway, which I can understand, and afaik it uses macros to implement them which is something we are vary wary of (especially reproducing the idea as part of our codebase). The complexity cost is not justified by the small benefit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct structural types inline:

```
scala> val a = new {def hello = null} -> 1 // by the way hello is accessible in a (but scala uses reflection for that)
a: (AnyRef{def hello: Null}, Int) = ($anon$1@68e2da47,1)

scala> var b = new {def hello = null} -> 2
b: (AnyRef{def hello: Null}, Int) = ($anon$1@77147ad6,2)

scala> b = a
b: (AnyRef{def hello: Null}, Int) = ($anon$1@68e2da47,1)

scala> var c = new {def helloooo = null} -> 1
c: (AnyRef{def helloooo: Null}, Int) = ($anon$1@38def4a2,1)

scala> c = a
<console>:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (AnyRef{def hello: Null}, Int)
 required: (AnyRef{def helloooo: Null}, Int)
       c = a
           ^
```

So, you can combine them with objects to give them type uniqueness:

```
 new {def myTypeName = null} -> myObject //now your myObject tagged with 'myTypeName', but your methods should be aware about tuples

 def mlp(x: ((Any, YourObjectsType), Int)) = x
```

Or (little bit slower beacause of reflection)

```
scala> def mlp( x: ({def obj: Symbol}, Int)) = x._1.obj -> x._2
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
mlp: (x: (AnyRef{def obj: Symbol}, Int))(Symbol, Int)

scala> mlp(new { def a1 = null; def obj = 'a1 } -> 1)
res18: (Symbol, Int) = ('a1,1)

scala> mlp(new { def a2 = null; def obj = 'a2 } -> 1)
res19: (Symbol, Int) = ('a2,1)
```

You can combine it with [tags](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Tagged+type.html) to annotate your type like:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> def markALittle[T](a: T) = Tag[T, MyLittleType](a)
markALittle: [T](a: T)scalaz.@@[T,MyLittleType]

scala> markALittle(new {def hello: Aaa = null})
res15: scalaz.@@[AnyRef{def hello: Aaa},MyLittleType] = $anon$1@a8c48e8
```

---

More tagging examples:

```
scala> trait MyLittleType

scala> trait Spike extends MyLittleType; val x = Tag[Symbol, Spike]('k1) -> 1
x: (scalaz.@@[Symbol,Spike], Int) = ('k1,1)

scala> trait Rainbow extends MyLittleType; val y = Tag[Symbol, Rainbow]('k2) -> 1
y: (scalaz.@@[Symbol,Rainbow], Int) = ('k2,1)

scala> val y: (scalaz.@@[Symbol,Spike], Int) = Tag[Symbol, Rainbow]('k1) -> 1
<console>:22: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (scalaz.@@[Symbol,Rainbow], Int)
 required: (scalaz.@@[Symbol,Spike], Int)
       val y: (scalaz.@@[Symbol,Spike], Int) = Tag[Symbol, Rainbow]('k1) -> 1


scala> val z: (scalaz.@@[Symbol,_ <: MyLittleType], Int) = Tag[Symbol, Rainbow]('k1) -> 1
z: (scalaz.@@[Symbol, _ <: MyLittleType], Int) = ('k1,1)
```

So, you can:

```
scala> def mlt[T <: MyLittleType](x :(scalaz.@@[Symbol,T], Int)) = x
mlt: [T <: MyLittleType](x: (scalaz.@@[Symbol,T], Int))(scalaz.@@[Symbol,T], Int)

scala> mlt(x)
res42: (scalaz.@@[Symbol,Spike], Int) = ('k1,1)

scala> mlt(y)
res43: (scalaz.@@[Symbol,Rainbow], Int) = ('k2,1)
```

Or just use:

```
scala> val x = Tag[Int, Rainbow](1)
x: scalaz.@@[Int,Rainbow] = 1

scala> val y = Tag[Int, Spike](1)
y: scalaz.@@[Int,Spike] = 1
```

You may operate  `x` as both `Int` using `Tag.unwrap(x)`, or just define `implicit def t[T] = Tag.unwrap[Int, T] _` to make no difference between Tag and Int, but be careful here - any non-tag oriented function will remove the tag)

Another inline type constructor solutions:

a) ugly

```
scala> class ___
defined class ___

scala> class __[T,U] extends ___
defined class __

scala> val x = Tag[Symbol, ___ __ ___]('k1) -> 1
x: (scalaz.@@[Symbol,__[___,___]], Int) = ('k1,1)

scala> var y = Tag[Symbol, ___ __ ___ __ ___]('k1) -> 1
y: (scalaz.@@[Symbol,__[__[___,___],___]], Int) = ('k1,1)

scala> y = x
<console>:59: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (scalaz.@@[Symbol,__[___,___]], Int)
 required: (scalaz.@@[Symbol,__[__[___,___],___]], Int)
       y = x
           ^

scala> def mlp[X <: scalaz.@@[Symbol, _]](x: (X, Int)) = x
mlp: [X <: scalaz.@@[Symbol, _]](x: (X, Int))(X, Int)

scala> mlp(x)
res106: (scalaz.@@[Symbol,__[___,___]], Int) = ('k1,1)
```

b) funny:

```
class - [B <: -[_, _], A <: symbolic[A]] (a: A, b: B) { 
    def -[T <: symbolic[T]](c: T) = new - (c, this)
}

trait symbolic[F <: symbolic[F]] { 
    def - [T <: symbolic[T]](b: T) = new - [single[F],T](b, new single(this.asInstanceOf[F]))
}

class single[T <: symbolic[T]](a: T) extends - [single[_],T](a, null)

val a = new a_; class a_ extends symbolic[a_]
val b = new b_; class b_ extends symbolic[b_]
val c = new c_; class c_ extends symbolic[c_] 
...

scala> val x = h-e-l-l-o -> 1
x: (-[o_,-[l_,-[l_,-[h_,end[e_]]]]], Int) = ($minus@350bc88,1)

scala> var y = h-e-l-l-o-o -> 2
y: (-[o_,-[o_,-[l_,-[l_,-[h_,end[e_]]]]]], Int) = ($minus@46d7fdc0,2)

scala> y = x
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (-[o_,-[l_,-[l_,-[h_,end[e_]]]]], Int)
 required: (-[o_,-[o_,-[l_,-[l_,-[h_,end[e_]]]]]], Int)
       y = x
           ^

scala> var z = h-e-l-l-o-o -> 2
z: (-[o_,-[o_,-[l_,-[l_,-[h_,end[e_]]]]]], Int) = ($minus@6b899d5d,2)

scala> z = y
z: (-[o_,-[o_,-[l_,-[l_,-[h_,end[e_]]]]]], Int) = ($minus@46d7fdc0,2)
```

Comment: Thanks, a couple of good ideas to puzzle over. I especially like the last one, as it has little syntactic overhead, doesn't use any library and is simple enough to understand by someone seeing it for the first time, hopefully passing the 'not too clever' test. BTW, is there a way to tell the compiler to use infix notation when printing the type? Right now the only problem of this solution is that errors are cryptic as hell. I ended up using just plain structural types in my code, which didn't allow the flexibility I wanted and were a little verbose, but at least eqsy to understand.

Comment: Yrw! didn't found a way to switch to infix notation (excluding compiler plugin or (?)macro). i've changed impl a little bit, now it prints: `a-b-c-a-b-c-a-b-c
res22: -[-[-[-[-[-[-[-[single[a_],b_],c_],a_],b_],c_],a_],b_],c_]`

Comment: Heh, I was just typing the exact same solution, but from a tablet, so you were quicker :) Thanks again, this look cool.

Comment: The goog part is that we can have trait Identifier :> - :> symbolic and derive classes for global, fixed keys from symbolic. In that case it might be syntactically more concise to make symbolic a parameterless type, and instead of A <: symbolic[A] have A :Symbolic and implicit def symbolic[A<:symbolic] :Symbolic[A]

Answer (score 0):

So, in order to stay simple, what about this?

```
object xt; val x = (xt, 1);
object yt; val y = (yt, 2);

def mlt(x: (_, Int)) = 42
mlt(x); mlt(y)
```

Okay I cheated, it's not really inline, but I think it's short enough for your need.
However, if you want to store a value in xt or yt, you'll have to use something longer:
`object xt {val get = 'k1}`